# How to configure App ID application on bluemix for web application authentication

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

Currently I am struggling to configure Google/Facebook authentication on 'APP ID' service provided in Bluemix catalog. While following the steps I am asked to configure Google and Facebook authentication. I chose to go with Google. Refer attached image, here I am asked to provide 'App Id' and 'App Secret'. As I think, 'App Id' is corresponding to 'Client Id' in Google developer console and similarly 'App Secret' is corresponding to 'Client Secret'. I have generated 'Client Id' and 'Client Secret' in Google Developer Console and the 'Redirect URI' which is auto generated.

I have provided that redirect uri in google developer console.

After this configuration I downloaded the Node.js project , deploy it in bluemix via `cf push` and then run this project but here I am getting the error 'redirect_uri doesn't belongs to the clientID'.

[image: image-1]
[image: image-2]

Comment: See here for logging out with App ID Node SDK https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067128/11476447.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add your application redirect URI in the identity providers page
[image: The redirect URI section in identity providers page]
if you downloaded the sample node js your redirect URI is by default
`{{YOUR_HOST}}/ibm/bluemix/appid/callback`
and you can change it if you like in app.js under the parameter `const CALLBACK_URL = "/ibm/bluemix/appid/callback";`, it has to be identical to the way you define in AppId dashboard

Comment: Thanks Asaf.

I have logged in to the custom app using APP ID but now I am not getting how to logout. I have provided a Logout button on home page and on clicking that page I am clearing the cookies but not getting logged out.  Any idea ?